# Nested model, trt, week and period, how to code this?

Tags: r, anova, modeling, interaction

I have a dataset and I want to see if there is a difference between trt, week and period. The data:

```
set.seed(1)
id <- rep(1:2,each=6)

trt <- c("A","A","A","B", "B", "B","A","A","A","B", "B", "B")
week <- rep(1:6,2)
period <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2) 
pointA <- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
pointB <- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
pointC <- sample(1:10,12, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id, trt, week, period, pointA, pointB, pointC)
df
  id trt week period pointA pointB pointC
1   1   A    1      1      3      7      3
2   1   A    2      1      4      4      4
3   1   A    3      1      6      8      1
4   1   B    4      2     10      5      4
5   1   B    5      2      3      8      9
6   1   B    6      2      9     10      4
7   2   A    1      1     10      4      5
8   2   A    2      1      7      8      6
9   2   A    3      1      7     10      5
10  2   B    4      2      1      3      2
11  2   B    5      2      3      7      9
12  2   B    6      2      2      2      7

dflmer <- lmer(formula=df[,i] ~   trt*week+ trt*period+ (1|id), data=df)
```

I don't know how to code this. I guess I shouldn't include two interaction terms, it doesnt work, I only get output from the first interaction term. But this is what I want to test.
Or should it be nested somehow, because weeks depend on period for each diet ...?
like `diet(week|period)`, or something!

Comment: What is Diet in your formula, does this refer to trt?

Comment: @psychonomics Yes! sorry, that was a type error!